# How SQLAlchemy `relationship` differs from foreign keys?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

The [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_2/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) gives an example of linking two tables, but it requires users to link the two tables at both the database level (with a foreign key), and the ORM level (with `relationship`):

```
user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")
```

I understand foreign keys, as they are needed whether you are using an ORM or not. What I don't understand is why users need to define the `relationship` at the ORM level. Isn't this repetitive work? Can't SQLAlchemy infer table relationship using foreign keys alone? What functionalities will be missing if there isn't `relationship` at the ORM level?